# How to make navbar-fixed-top to move along for second menu

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html, twitter-bootstrap

Hi guys I have my jsfiddle [here](https://jsfiddle.net/b4751wkp/)

```css
.top-category-div {
    background: black;
    color: white;
    margin-top: 0px;
    margin-left: -66%;
    padding-bottom: 54px;

}

.main-menu-div {
  margin-top:70px;
}

@media (min-width: 1280px) {
    .container{  
        width: 1280px;
        padding-left: 0;
        padding-left: 0px;
        padding-right: 0px;
        margin-right: auto;
        margin-left: auto;
        padding-left: 15px;
        padding-right: 15px;
    }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
    <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top" >
            <div class="container">
                <div class="navbar-header pull-left">
                    <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed " data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1" aria-expanded="false">
                        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    </button>
                </div>
                
                <div class="collapse navbar-collapse responsive-menu-button" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
                    <ul class="nav navbar-nav top-header-left-list">
                        <li><a href="#">Website Review <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Our Blog</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">About us</a></li>
                    </ul>
                    <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right top-header-right-list ">
                        <li><a href="#"><span class='heart-fav-text'>Your favorites</span>
                                        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-heart fav-heart"></span> 
                                        <span class='your-favorite-score'>34</span>
                            </a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="active"><a href="#" class="btn">login <span class='or_text'> or </span> subscribe</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        </nav>
    <div class="container main-menu-div ">
        <ul class="pull-right list-inline left-breadcrumbs">
            <li> <a href="#">Contact Us  </a></li>
            <li> <a href="#">How we work  </a></li>
            <li> <a href="#">about our site review </a></li>
        </ul>
        <div class="col-sm-2 section-logo hidden-xs">
            <div class="img-resposnsive">
                <img src="http://placehold.it/193x55" alt="logo" class="img-responsive">    
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-5">
          <ul class="nav nav-pills ">
            <li><a href="">my menu part1</a></li>
            
              <li><a href="">my menu2</a></li>
              <li><a href="">my menu3</a></li>
            </ul>
          </div>
        <div class="col-sm-5 search-box-div">
            <div class="input-group stylish-input-group">
                <input type="text" class="form-control form-group"  placeholder="Search" >
                <span class="input-group-addon">
                    <button type="submit">
                        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></span>
                    </button>  
                </span>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div>
      dummy    dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy
           dummy    dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy     dummy    dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy     dummy    dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy     dummy    dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy     dummy    dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy     dummy    dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy     dummy    dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy     dummy    dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy     dummy    dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy     dummy    dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy     dummy    dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy     dummy    dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy     dummy    dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy     dummy    dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy     dummy    dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy     dummy    dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy     dummy    dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy   dummy
    </div>
```

I want my submenu below the navbar should behave as navbar-fixed-top behaves. I have a site link here I want something like [demo_site](https://bigbangerp.com/)

When user scrolls down I want my second menu to be moved along the top, I want only my menu part1 my menu2 my menu3 these 3 and logo to be moved along the top. Rest all which are in first navbar can be hidden. Any help will be appreciated

Comment: Some one please have attention on this question